# How expensive is comparing two unordered sets for equality?

Tags: c++, set, complexity-theory, equality, unordered-set

Given two `std::set`s, one can simply iterate through both sets simultaneously and compare the elements, resulting in linear complexity. This doesn't work for `std::unordered_set`s, because the elements may be stored in any order. So how expensive is `a == b` for `std::unordered_set`?

Comment: Do you have an efficient way to check set membership (for example are they backed by hashtables)?

Comment: In the clear, straightforward, easy to comprehend and understand words of the C++ Standard:  "Two unordered containers `a` and `b` compare equal if `a.size() == b.size()` and, for every equivalent-key group `[Ea1,Ea2)` obtained from `a.equal_range(Ea1)`, there exists an equivalent-key group `[Eb1,Eb2)` obtained from `b.equal_range(Ea1)`, such that `distance(Ea1, Ea2) == distance(Eb1, Eb2)` and `is_permutation(Ea1, Ea2, Eb1)` returns `true`. For `unordered_set`...the complexity of `operator==`...is proportional to `N` in the average case and to `N^2` in the worst case, where `N` is `a.size()`."

Comment: Some related C++20 discussion that might be of interest: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0809r0.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Complexity of `operator==` and `operator!=`:

Linear complexity in the average case. N<sup>2</sup> in the worst case, where N is the size of the container.

More details in the standard §23.2.5, point 11:

For `unordered_set` and `unordered_map`, the complexity of `operator==` (i.e., the number of calls to the `==` operator of the `value_type`, to the predicate returned by
`key_equal()`, and to the hasher returned by `hash_function()`) is proportional to `N` in the average case and to N<sup>2</sup> in the worst case, where `N` is `a.size()`.

Answer (score 14):

The very worst case is O(n²).

But unordered sets are in fact ordered by hash.
So it is possible to compare the hashes (if this fails the sets cannot be equal) and then verify that same hashes (linear) have real same values (O(n²) for different values with the same hash) behind.

In the best case this is O(n).

Normally the complexity tends to O(n) if the hash function is "good" (different objects -> always different hash) and to O(n²) if the hash function is "bad" (everything always has the same hash value)

Comment: "hash function is good (different objects -> always different hash)" -> different hashes can be true even for a terrible hash algorithm (e.g. hash strings of up to 128 characters by returning a 8*128-bit hash value cloned from the string), but mod that into the number of buckets and the result is ugly. When there's no special insight into inputs that facilitates collision avoidance, a good hash function post modding generally has collisions in the ratio of used to unused buckets... which does still result in O(n) averages.

Comment: @TonyDelroy: Thank you for pointing this out! A "good hash" must not only return "different values", but also "well distributed" respect to the buckets (The hash space should be uniform and prime respect to the buckets, just to minimize  the effect you mention)